# Scrolling up and down with HTML page in android

Tags: android

I had put an question in StackOverflow yesterday but could not get the answer.
I am attaching the url for the same [Question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790080/scrolling-with-static-html-page-not-working-saved-in-assets-folder-in-android) looking for the answer.
I am using WebView to render the page and cannot scroll up and down with the html saved in asset folder.
Runs perfectly in emulator but in device I cannot scroll.

Looking forward to your reply.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this is the code

code for xml

```
<ScrollView android:scrollbars="vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
  <LinearLayout 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      android:orientation="vertical"> 
     <WebView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/help"/> 
     <ImageButton 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:id="@+id/close" android:background="@drawable/ok_button"  
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_gravity="center" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
  </LinearLayout> 
</ScrollView>
```

code in jave

```
try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("help.html");

        // We guarantee that the available method returns the total
        // size of the asset...  of course, this does mean that a single
        // asset can't be more than 2 gigs.
        int size = is.available();

        // Read the entire asset into a local byte buffer.
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();

        // Convert the buffer into a Java string.
        String text = new String(buffer);

        final String mimeType = "text/html";
        final String encoding = "utf-8";

        // Finally stick the string into the text view.
        WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.help);
        wv.loadData(text, mimeType, encoding);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Should never happen!
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Comment: Reddy P thanks absolutely perfect answer. I was missing LinearLayout inside ScrollView so I removed root Layout as ScrollView and used LinearLayout and works fine. But Scrolling for WebView does not work if the root layout is ScrollView, that is any WebView Scrolling would not work if it is under ScrollView.